# How to delete rows from both tables linked to each table by their primary keys?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I want to delete the rows from users and hobbies where they are connected by ID and customersID respectively.

I am using Microsoft access to do that. I linked the 2 primary keys from both table.

[image]

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim str As String = IDbox.Text
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) Then
        MsgBox("Error") : Exit Sub
    End If

    Access.AddParam("@ID", str)
    Access.ExecQuery("DELETE FROM users where ID = @ID")
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Access.Exception) Then MsgBox(Access.Exception) : Exit Sub
    update_Table()
    update_TableHobby()
End Sub
```

How can I delete rows in both table?

Like currently if I execute the query it will just delete from users table but not from Hobbies table.

Comment: When you have created the relationship between the two tables did you set the apply referential integrity and the cascade delete options?

Comment: This looks like a design flaw. There should be a Hobbies table and a Users Table. Then have a junction table with Hobby ID and User ID.

Comment: What you show is a one-to-one relationship which could just be a single table. However, having 3 yes/no fields for activities is poor design. What if you need to add more activities? @Mary describes a conventional many-to-many relational structure. Deleting data should be a rare event.

Comment: The referal integrity cascade options works well. Thanks. But why is it a design flows? What design would be better for that? I am also doing it just to learn VB and Microsoft access.

Comment: One-to-one relationship is rarely used and usually unnecessary. These two tables could be only one. The flaw is using multiple hobby/activity yes/no fields. What if you want to add another hobby/activity, say yoga? Have to redesign table, queries, forms, reports, code. Research topic of database normalization and many-to-many relationship.

Comment: As suggested by June7: `Users` table with `UserID` column as primary key. `Hobbies` table with `HobbyID` column as primary key and `Name` column or the like. You would then have a row each where "Tennis", "Swimming" and "Dancing" were the `Name` values. You would then have a third `UserHobbies` table with `UserID` and `HobbyID` columns s foreign keys. If, for instance, a user played tennis and danced then you would add two rows to the `UserHobbies` table with their `UserID` and the `HobbyID` for those hobbies. That is a proper many:many relationship.

Comment: There is no enforced relationship or a cascade delete setup in the database. This is as other noted a very nice  mess. So, simple solution to keep this mess working? You simply need to delete the Hobbies record (which may, or may not exist), and then you need to delete the user from user table. So you have to execute two delete commands.